# Medallion with compartment inside

Tags: word-choice, expressions

How can you call a pendant/medallion that can open, in which you can put a little object in it?
Even if it has to be described with a few words, it's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **locket** is a pendant that opens to reveal a space used for storing a photograph or other small item such as a curl of hair.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locket)

Comment: Thanks! And how do you call the space inside it? Is "concelead compartment" a correct way to call it?

Comment: If I'm correct, a Google search for "in the locket's" gives no relevant results. People would just say 'inside the locket' or 'the inside of the locket'; a 'concealed compartment' usually means one you didn't suspect (unless you're Sherlock).